# Fetching the child element in a column from salesforce

Tags: python, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-chatter

I am querying the data from salesforce using python

The soql that I am using is
select {column} from {salesforce_object_name} where  type = 'sports' "

In this, for few columns, I am getting the results like this
OrderedDict([('attributes', OrderedDict([('type', 'Contact'), ('url', 'hvhcgcuhkjhkncvgcgc')])), ('Name', 'NA - Holding Off')]).
Actually, I want the value which is in the Name field. In this case, NA - Holding Off.

In the column parameter in the query, I am passing as column_name.Name but I am still getting the results as I mentioned above. Someone pls help

Answer (score 0):

You can access the name value by using: `column_name['Name']`

e.g.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

dict_ = OrderedDict([('attributes', OrderedDict([('type', 'Contact'), ('url', 'hvhcgcuhkjhkncvgcgc')])), ('Name', 'NA - Holding Off')])

print(dict_['Name']) #will output 'NA - Holding Off'
```

[More details on OrderedDict.](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ordereddict-in-python/)